# Why immutable does not complain on attempt to change value

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I'm looking through the documentation for [Immutable library](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) and was quite surprised by the fact that attempt to change a value on immutable collection just ignoring the action and does not throw an exception.

This is example from the documentation

```js
import Immutable = require('immutable');
var map1: Immutable.Map<string, number>;
map1 = Immutable.Map({a:1, b:2, c:3});
var map2 = map1.set('b', 50);
map1.get('b'); // 2
map2.get('b'); // 50
```

Why is it implemented in this way, wouldn't be better to throw an exception and therefore expose the error in the code?

**UPDATE**

I'm more java developer and I instinctively assume that behavior of immutable collections in JS will be similar to Java. Java's immutable collections will throw UnsupportedOperationException on the attempt to modify the collection.

I appreciate that javascript is a different language and it can have its own rules and view on how it should behave. I'm not saying that it is wrong I just want to understand the motivation behind the decision to allow calls to set/push etc methods on immutable collection.

Comment: You don't change value of anything. What line should have thrown an exception?

Comment: I know, I think the possibility to execute `map1.set('b', 50)` may lead to a bug wich could be hard to find.

Comment: `map1.set` does not mutate `map1`. So what bug something that changes nothing may cause?

Comment: If I do 'map1.set('b', 50)' and I as a 'dumb' developer will assume that the value map1.get('b') will be 50. What if it is not clear that map is actually immutable?

Comment: Well, you're using the library whose name contains `Immutable`. Plus it's your obligation to read the documentation. I don't see how this is a library problem.

Comment: An immutable libary without that capability would most likely be useless. How would you concat 2 lists or do anything useful with them ? You can't expect everything to be constructed from a literal or be available at compiletime. At some point someone somehow has to construct a list.

Strings are immutable as well in java eg. That doesn't mean you can't assign a new value to your reference. The point of immutable stuff is that it's atomic and consistent in itself and can be savely handled across threads. And the objects here are indeed immutable. The reference to them however is mutable.

Comment: Your own test even illustrates the immutability. You should research it more.

Comment: The reason java throws an error is that it's hard typed. It can't dynamically return any object, just like javascript. The set method in java returns either bool or void, that means no useful behaviour can be implemented. On the otherhand when handling Strings you can use += etc without any errors eventhough Strings are immutable.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful it is not my test code, I mentioned that it borrowed from the documentation. You provided a good point that Stirng in java also immutable but still has methods 'repalce' and 'concat' which could be thoughts as modifiers.

Comment: @HopefullyHelpful so it is implemented in this way because it is not possible to throw an exception in JS? This could be a perfect answer.

Comment: No, its possible, but unnessary. Java is forced to implement the way it does because of inheritance and hardtyping. You could give the JS method another name like returnAlteredCloneAndSetClonesElement(), but why? It's clear in every context what object you are handling you can inspect every method and it's behavior and even set it for indivual instances. There are no types and hardtyping and polymorphy in JS.

Comment: If you have a list of lists in JS you can determine the Type of every list at runtime and use it's behaviour without casting.

Answer (score 1):

Notice how it returned a new object, though:

```
var map2 = map1.set('b', 50);
map1.get('b'); // 2
map2.get('b'); // 50
map1.get('b'); // 2 <--- It's still 2!
```

I do agree to a certain extend that maybe this shouldn't be allowed, but its handy to have it function like that, sometimes you want a new object with a key modified. At any rate, it would failing its job if this happened:

```
map1 = Immutable.Map({a:1, b:2, c:3});
map1.get('b'); // 2
var map2 = map1.set('b', 50);
map1.get('b'); // 50 <--- Oh, no!!!
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: So I assume it is kind of the same as using `withMutations` method. It is the usage of `set` method on immutable object confused me. What if I just do `map2.set('b',100)`?

Comment: Then map2.get('b') would still be 50, does that make sense?

Comment: "I do agree to a certain extend that maybe this shouldn't be allowed" --- WAT? Why should a `.set` method be disallowed?

Comment: @zerkms Stop exposing me like this, I'm trying to sympathize with the OP... You would understand if you only had like 500 rep points like me. Totally kidding (partially), and I don't know, ".set" doesn't seem THAT intuitive, but it is very useful, so yeah, I'm all for it.

Comment: " ".set" doesn't seem THAT intuitive" --- so one should check the documentation. Software development is about precise facts, not intuition and guesses.

Comment: @zerkms You're right, software development is about precise facts, not intuition and guesses.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were looking for frozen objects, but instead happened on immutable because it's a namesake with the immutable collections in Java. The immutable js serves a very different purpose aside from providing immutable encapsulation around native mutable types. It allows easy :p and rich structure modifications too. Hence this behavior. I think if all you are interested in is to have a frozen object which doesn't allow for any modifications, please take a look at `Object.freeze`.